# TP-Link WN951N (Atheros AR922X) crashing randomly on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a big problem with my wireless card TP-Link WN951N (Atheros AR922X) on Windows 10 64 bits.
The network adapter stops randomly and disconnect me from Internet.
The available networks disappear.
Sometimes, in the devices manager, there is a warning before the wireless card, explaining that Windows can't start the adaptater (code 10)...
Sometimes, desactivate/activate the adaptater solves the problem but it arrives that the adaptater can't be activated until restarting the computer.

The1 BIOS is up to date.
The driver provided by Microsoft for this card dates from the 12th March 2015.
TP-Link says me that Windows doesn't validate any driver version for this version of Windows.
On the Internet, I discover this strange unofficial website, with more recent drivers (and empty forums) : https://www.atheros-drivers.com/download-driver-for-Atheros-chipset-with-id-32-and-Windows10-64bit.html

Qualcomm explains officially he decided to stop giving generic drivers on its website since February 2015.

What do you think should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Atheros has the best drivers for Linux that have no closed-source blobs in their firmware, every bit of it is open-source. When I am buying wireless stuff this is my reason to look for something that has Atheros chipset in it.

Unless you can upgrade your Win10 to Ubuntu or some other flavor of Linux, I would just download the unofficial Win10 drivers you mentioned. I guess it is such a big hassle to get Windows logo certifications that the company just stopped paying the Microsoft tax.

Comment: Thank you for your optimistic answer ! But how to know that's not a "hacking driver" ? Unfortunately, I don't find any "independant" feedback about this website... And there is no mention about their creators.

Comment: Qualcomm just states the business bulls**t [on their website](https://www.qualcomm.com/drivers). Basically they say if TP-Link does not support Win10, they will not provide you with a solution either. As a software engineer my trust in closed-source software companies is quite flawed, so I do not trust a driver better just because someone paid money for a signature from Microsoft. But it is your choice in the end.